# getting the length of array provided array is being accessed through pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, c

For ex.
I have a function

```
void len(int *A){ // or we have its reference

// can I find the length of array here or
// we just need to pass the length along as the parameter

}
```

Comment: You can't. `A` is a pointer, not an array. Use `std::vector` instead of passing length explicitly unless you really have to. Also take a look at [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) - it will be available in C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I find the length of array here or we just need to pass the length along as the parameter

You can't find the length once the array has decayed into a pointer so one option is to supply the length as a parameter as you said yourself.

Another option is to not let it decay into a pointer:

```
template<size_t N>
void len(int(&A)[N]) {
    // N is the length
}
```

Or you could use a `std::vector<int>`:

```
void len(std::vector<int>& A) {
    // A.size() returns the length
}
```

Comment: Theoretically you can’t, but in some cases where a sentinel is present it is possible. Of course it is important that the sentinel is unique in that array.

Comment: @Michi Yes, that's a workaround.